# Prove that $ \ker(A) = \ker(A^2) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A \in M_{n \times n}$. I know that $ A^T = \pm A $ and I need show that $ \ker(A) = \ker(A^2) $. I was wandering about diagonal form but a skew matrix need not be diagonalizable.

Comment: what do you know about $\ker (A^TA)$?

Comment: for sure i can see that $ Ker(A) \subset Ker(A^TA) $

Comment: $\ker(A)=\ker(A^TA)=\ker(\pm A^2)=\ker(A^2)$ by the duplicate.